# How does AH header in IPSec prevents replay attacks?

Tags: computer-networks

According to Tanenbaum's *Modern operating systems*,

> The purpose of this field is to detect replay attacks. These sequence numbers may not wrap around. If all $2^{32}$ are exhausted, a new security association must be established to continue communication.

According to Forouzan's *Data communications and networking*,

> In both protocols, replay attacks are prevented by using sequence numbers and a sliding receiver window. Each IPsec header contains a unique sequence number when the security association (SA) is established.
> It ranges from $0$ to $2^{32}-1$.
> When the sequence number reaches its maximum, it is reset to 0, the old SA is deleted, and a new one is established. To prevent duplicate packets, IPsec mandates the use of a fixed size window at receiver.

Can someone elaborate this with an example?